# ASCII odd character

Tags: windows, character, ascii

So I was using Notepad++ for and I accidentally pressed a combination of some SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER+WINDOWS KEY or something like this, I really don't know the combination, and I got an odd character, which reads "ETX". Here is an [image](http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1404/11/a/a5044ea060ff.png).

I'm curious about the character, I've never seen it before. While trying to google it, it doesn't show in the search box, and by querying a search, it searches "?" symbols equal to how many times i pasted the character in the search box,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character

Comment: The end of text character (ETX) marked the end of the data of a message